# CSS and Javascript is not applied to a content rendered from h:outputText with escape="false"

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, google-cloud-datastore

A content rendered from h:outText with escape="false" is not bound to the css or javascript applicable for that page. Actually I am trying to use syntax highlighters to highlight my syntax within a post. The post is stpored in database and displaying it in a JSF page with h:outputText tag by setting escape attribute as false. It renders the page as expected with all html tags being processed but css or javascript applicable to the code blocks within that post is not applied. Below  is my jsf page which retrieves html from database and shows it through h:outputText tag. The retrieved content has syntax it needs to be highlighted.

```
   <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        template="/templates/ui.xhtml">

 <ui:define name="head">
    <title>tekBytes-#{tutorialController.tut.title}</title>

<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
<link href="/rainbow/themes/pastie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/rainbow/rainbow.min.js"></script>
<script src="/rainbow/language/generic.js"></script>
<script src="/rainbow/language/java.js"></script>
<script src="/rainbow/language/css.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
/*
 * do some jQuery magic on load
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
    function showHiddenParagraphs() {
        $("pre.hidden").fadeIn(500);
    }
    setTimeout(showHiddenParagraphs, 1000);
});

</script>
  </ui:define>
  <ui:define name="content">
  <div style="margin:20px">
  <h1>#{tutorialController.tut.title}</h1>
  <br/>
  <h:outputText value="#{tutorialController.tut.contentStr}" escape="false"/>
  </div>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In JSF 2.0, all your web resources files like css, images or
>   JavaScript, should put in “resources” folder, under the root of your
>   web application (same folder level with “WEB-INF“).

Put your js / css in `resources/js` and `resources/css` folder and access them with `<h:outputStylesheet` and `<h:outputScript`

Like this

```
<h:outputScript name="js/rainbow.min.js" />
```

and

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/language/css.js" />
```

and so on...

---

Also read this : [Resources (Library) In JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/)

Answer (score 0):

Potential problem could be in number of places here , verify the following in order.

```
    1) Check your CSS files are getting loaded by the browser 
by monitoring the request in developer tools on Firefox or chrome.

   https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview?hl=fr

    2) check the source of your html to see if that looks 
fine and tags are not encoded etc. 

    3) verify your CSS to see it works and it doesn't have missing semicolon,
 brackets,quotes etc by adding it to a test html page on your machine.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved. The actual issue was that the html stored in database was generated through the p:editor which has put so many div tags around every line, so when it is rendered through h:outputText tag  the css or javascript is not able to parse the code blocks that are applicable for syntax highlighting because of surrounded divs and other tags. So I have removed all of these unnecessary tags before storing it in the database. Thanks, everyone for the replies.